# The argument type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, widget, qr-code, pubspec.yaml

The argument type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QR Code Generator'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: QrImage(
            data: websiteUrl,
            version: QrVersions.auto,
            size: 200.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

pubspec.yaml

`qr_flutter: ^4.0.0`
 `sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'`

Lowered sdk to below 2.12.0 to remove null check but error remains the same

Comment: Welcome to SO! Taking a look at the docs. I think you might want to use `QrImageView` instead of `QrImage`. Does that make sense?

Comment: `QrImage` class is defined in dart package `qr`, and it is not a child of Widget class.

Comment: QrImageView worked.